# FFMPEG commands

Tags: php, ffmpeg

How do I on converted video file (from avi to flv) add watermark using second ffmpeg command?

It can do it in a single command, however, when ffmpeg converting video file it reduce as well and the quality of the watermark png image.

The single command that I'm using right now looks like:

```
$ffmpeg_cmd2 = "$config[path_to_ffmpeg] -i $raw_video_path -copyts -ar 44100 -s 320x240 -vf 'movie=0:png:image/wmk.png [wm];[in][wm] overlay=10:main_h-overlay_h-10 [out]' $new_flv";

@exec("$ffmpeg_cmd2");
```

What I want to do is that the quality of png file remains unchanged. Can I achieve that by runing another ffmpeg command to add vatermark after the conversion of video is done?

How can I fire another ffmepg command after the first one is finished?

Thanks for all suggestions.

Comment: Your example code won't work properly as variables of the form `$name[key]` need to be surrounded with braces `{}` when being interpolated, like this, `{$config['path_to_ffmpeg']}`. Also notice how the key name is quoted; unquoted key names are incorrect and are also a lot slower.

Comment: @Delan Azabani - Thanks for your comment Delan. This command is working fine on my website and all avi files are converted using phpmotion script and this command.

Comment: Unless the container format allows embedding uncompressed images in a separated stream (which would not be a watermark then), there is no way to have them merged in without lossy compression artefacts. You will have to raise the encoding quality to avoid it.

Comment: @mario -How can I do embedding uncompressed images in a separated stream?

Comment: @Sergio. You have to invent a container format that supports it.

Comment: @mario seems too complicated for me and my level of knowledge of ffmpeg

Answer (score 0):

> How can I fire another ffmepg command after the first one is finished?

Just call `exec()` a second time.